# claymore miner 9.6 gives error CUDA error - cannot allocate big buffer for DAG. Check readme.txt for possible solutions

Tags: claymore

i have 6 gpu nvidia 1060 6gb but when i run my batch file this error raise by claymore miner 
CUDA error - cannot allocate big buffer for DAG. Check readme.txt for possible solutions.
i set my virtual memory min 16000 and max 20000 but still error raise and unable to mine eth

Answer (score 0):

adding -eres 0 solved the issue for me